# Create preseed partitions

Tags: 14.04, server, partitioning, preseed

I am looking to get

- A fixed 10GB / partition
- A fixed 1GB SWAP
- All the rest of the space in an ext4 partition

With the following code, the rest of the space is being put on the swap, can someone help?

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
  boot-root ::                                            \
          10000 10000 10000 ext4                      \
                $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                  $lvmok{ } method{ format } format{ }              \
                  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                 mountpoint{ / }                         \
          .                                               \
          64 512 1000  linux-swap                         \
                  $lvmok{ } method{ swap } format{ }                \
          .                                               \
          10000 10000 -1 ext4                      \
                  method{ format } format{ }              \
                  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
          .
```

Comment: How large is your drive?

Comment: 60GB (this can vary though, up to 128 gb)

Comment: I'm not sure why you want a 1 GB swap, but after that I would keep everything on `/` and make it 59 GB.

Comment: Thanks but i need the partition layout to be as i mentioned above since i have other plans for the second partition that i want to create there (the big one)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use lvm method in  `d-i partman-auto/method string`?
Partitioner doesn't understand what is the rest partition method - if it's under lvm, you should use `$lvmok{ }`

Check these preseed files https://github.com/bonddim/linux-unattended-installation/blob/master/ubuntu/preseed